# Problem with denominator in transformation

Tags: calculus

I can't understand where the 2 comes from in the following transformation.
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial k}f(k)=\frac{\partial}{\partial k}k^{0.5}=\frac{1}{2k^{0.5}}$$
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: HINT: if $y=x^n$ then $dy/dx=nx^{n-1}$. Look at what this gives for $n=0.5$.

Answer (score 3):

Having looked at your previous question, I see the issue here.  The key point is that we are computing a *partial derivative* here.  $\partial$ is not a number that gets canceled out.

The derivative of $f(k) = k^{\frac12}$ is
\begin{equation*}
f'(k) = \frac12 k^{-\frac12}.
\end{equation*}.

Comment: Wow. I would've never pinpointed that issue with OP so easily! +1 for the great answer.

Answer (score 0):

First note that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial k}k^n=nk^{n-1}$$
So here's how the $2$ appears 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial k}k^{0.5}= \frac{\partial}{\partial k}k^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}k^{\frac{1}{2}-1}
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{2}k^{-\frac{1}{2}}= \frac{1}{2k^{\frac{1}{2}}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}
$$

Comment: thanks alot that was very helpful

Comment: @user170810, glad I could help.